# Why is refresh token not being returned from TokenRefreshView?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using DRF-simple-jwt to implement auth. Since I want the tokens to be returned in a cookie instead of the response, I'm using the code I found in this [github issue](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/issues/71#issuecomment-762927394), where people have a workaround for sending the token in the cookie (as this is not implemented in the package).

The issue for me is, in the CookieTokenRefreshView, "refresh" is not present in the response data. Because of which I'm getting a 500. The specific error is:

```
ValueError: The view team.views.auth_viewset.view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead
```

None is being returned because the else condition is not being handled in the finalize_response of CookieTokenRefreshView. Why is it not present?

The CookieTokenRefreshView:

```
class CookieTokenRefreshView(TokenRefreshView):
    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        print("REFRESH -> ",response.data.get("refresh"))
        if response.data.get("refresh"):
            cookie_max_age = 3600 * 24 * 14
            response.set_cookie(
                "refresh_token", 
                response.data["refresh"],
                max_age=cookie_max_age,
                httponly=True, 
                secure=True,
                samesite='Strict'
            )
            # don't return tokens in response
            del response.data["refresh"]

            return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
    serializer_class = CookieTokenRefreshSerializer
```

Apologies if this is a dumb question, I'm very new to both django and backend in general.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer here, so others don't spend as much time debugging this as I did. It turns out the code mentioned in the github issue is wrong, as in the refresh view, it is checking for `response.data["refresh"]`, which is None, because the refresh token isn't what is being returned, it's the access token.

The code should instead be:

```
class CookieTokenRefreshView(TokenRefreshView):
    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        if response.data.get("access"):
            cookie_max_age = 3600
            response.set_cookie(
                "access_token", 
                response.data["access"],
                max_age=cookie_max_age,
                httponly=True, 
                secure=True,
                samesite='Strict'
            )
            # don't return tokens in response
            del response.data["access"]

            return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
    serializer_class = CookieTokenRefreshSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

The presence of the refresh token in the response.data depends on the value of ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS. You can set it to true in settings.py to receive the refresh token along with the access token. Therefore, you will get a pair of tokens. Also,  remember to delete both values from the response body.
`SIMPLE_JWT = { ... "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True, ...`